# LINQ lambda - OrderByDescending is adding undesired select

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda, sql-order-by

I'm working with a pretty wild lambda query. Here is my initial LINQ lambda statement (not being sorted/ordered by):

```
var query = orders.Join(customers, o => o.CustomerID, c => c.ID, (o, c) => new { o, c })
                .Join(ordersections, o => o.o.ID, os => os.OrderID, (o, os) => new { o.o, o.c, os })
                .Join(tickets, o => o.os.ID, t => t.OrderSectionID, (o, t) => new { o.o, o.c, o.os, t })
                .Join(events, o => o.t.EventID, e => e.id, (o, e) => new { o.o, o.c, o.os, o.t, e })
                .Join(clients, o => o.e.ClientID, cl => cl.id, (o, cl) => new { o.o, o.c, o.os, o.t, o.e, cl })
                .Join(venues, o => o.e.VenueID, v => v.VenueID, (o, v) => new ModelsCs.LINQ.CustomerSearchResult { order = o.o, customer = o.c, orderSection = o.os, ticket = o.t, evt = o.e, client = o.cl, venue = v })
                         .AsExpandable()
                         .Where(predicate) // from PredicateBuilder
                         .GroupBy(x => new
                         {
                             // variables to group by

                         })                         
                         .Select(s => new CustomerSearchResult
                         {
                             // Selecting the variables, all good and fun!
                         });
```

The SQL that is generated is as follows:

```
SELECT <correct variables to select> 
FROM [dbo].[Order] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customer] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Customer] = ([t1].[Customer])
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrderSection] AS [t2] ON [t0].[Order] = [t2].[Order]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ticket] AS [t3] ON [t2].[OrderSection] = [t3].[OrderSection]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Event] AS [t4] ON [t3].[Event] = [t4].[Event]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Client] AS [t5] ON [t4].[Client] = ([t5].[Client])
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Venue] AS [t6] ON [t4].[Venue] = ([t6].[Venue])
WHERE ([t5].[Brand] = @p0)
    AND ([t0].[Brand] = @p1)
    AND ([t4].[EventStart] >= @p2)
    AND ([t0].[OrderDateTime] >= @p3)
    AND ([t1].[email] LIKE @p4)
GROUP BY <correct group by variables>
```

Beautiful! *But I need to order the results*, so I also want this at the end:

```
...
ORDER BY SortingVariable1 desc
```

**(^^^^ THIS IS WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO)**

*Here is what I have already tried:*

So I tried adding this to my LINQ lambda statement:

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.SortingVariable1)
```

But this is now the SQL code that is generated:

```
SELECT <correct variables to select>
FROM (
    SELECT <correct GROUP BY variables>
    FROM [dbo].[Order] AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customer] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Customer] = ([t1].[Customer])
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrderSection] AS [t2] ON [t0].[Order] = [t2].[Order]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ticket] AS [t3] ON [t2].[OrderSection] = [t3].[OrderSection]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Event] AS [t4] ON [t3].[Event] = [t4].[Event]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Client] AS [t5] ON [t4].[Client] = ([t5].[Client])
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Venue] AS [t6] ON [t4].[Venue] = ([t6].[Venue])
    WHERE ([t5].[Brand] = @p0)
        AND ([t0].[Brand] = @p1)
        AND ([t4].[EventStart] >= @p2)
        AND ([t0].[OrderDateTime] >= @p3)
        AND ([t1].[email] LIKE @p4)
    GROUP BY <correct group by variables>
    ) AS [t7]
ORDER BY [t7].[SortingVariable1] DESC
```

No matter where in my lambda statement I put that `.OrderByDescending`, it doesn't work correctly.

My question: Does anyone know how I can alter my LINQ Lambda statement to **correctly** add an `ORDER BY SortingVariable1 DESC` to the end of the generated SQL statement?

Comment: I don't see the problem? I wouldn't be worried by this extra `select`. I'd be more concern on how you get the data and if you use EF then to use navigation properties

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work correctly"? Does the query not return the stuff that you want, or the order does not match what you have specified, or is it just that you get a more complex SQL?

Answer (score 2):

The outer `SELECT` by itself is not a problem, because it does not come with an additional overhead of descernable magnitude. The addition of nesting allows SQL generator do sorting on any of the returned fields, even the calculated ones, without including the computation twice.

This behavior is due to a limitation of SQL illustrated by the example below:

```
SELECT A+B as A_plus_B
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY A_plus_B -- <=== This does not work
```

The query above must be re-written either with the computation repeated twice, i.e.

```
SELECT A+B as A_plus_B
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY A+B -- <=== Computation is repeated
```

or with a nested query or a CTE:

```
SELECT A_plusB FROM (
    SELECT A+B as A_plus_B
    FROM MyTable
)
ORDER BY A_plus_B -- <=== This works
```

LINQ's SQL generator takes the second approach, producing the statement that you see.

Answer (score -1):

It *is* correctly adding the `Order By`.  It is in the nature of auto-generated code that it is often not going to be as pretty as human generated code.  It'll often be more verbose in what it writes, simply because generating such code is often easier.

If you want to have *exactly* a certain set of SQL code, you'll need to write it by hand. If you want to let it be automatically generated for you then you'll have to be satisfied with less pretty but perfectly correct and equally functional code.